# Android: Image from assets folder is smaller than it should be

Tags: android, image, assets

I have problem when I try to set an image to a `ImageView` browsed from assets folder. When I place the same image in the drawable folder and use `imageView.setImageResource(R.id.image);` it is larger and fits the screen better than the image browsed by the previous method. Is there a way to resize the image so that it fits the screen exactly the same way as usual.

Here is the layout file and the code in java.

```
        AssetManager manager = getActivity().getAssets();       
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = manager.open("images/" + mQuestion.getQImage() + ".png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        ImageView qImageView = (ImageView) questionView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView_qImage);
        qImageView.setImageBitmap(image);



  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView_qImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/questionTopBottomMargin"
    android:background="@color/radioButtonStrokeColor"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:padding="1px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Do you have multiple dpi versions of that image in the drawables folders?

Comment: No there is only one

Comment: Did you try the suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749044/android-scaling-imageview-from-setimagebitmap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you place an image in drawable folder then the images are classified on density of screen while if  you put images in assest folder then android need to calculate density.

If you want to use images from assest folder then this code will help you.

```
Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;
drawable = Drawable.createFromResourceStream(context.getResources(), null, is, srcName, opts);
```

see here

[Image loaded from assets folder comes in different size than res/drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580261/image-loaded-from-assets-folder-comes-in-different-size-than-res-drawable)

[Android: Accessing images from assets/drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400101/android-accessing-images-from-assets-drawable-folders)

Answer (score 0):

If you place images in the drawables folder they will be scaled by some functions it they load them from resources. This will not happen with images in assets folder which you load yourself.

Answer (score 0):

### ***[Have a look at android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)***

---

1. You should always use images from the `drawable` folder
2. There are different `drawable` folders in android
   (`drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-ldpi`)
3. Android will decide which folder image should be drawn depending on
   the phone `requirements` and `resolution`
4. Use [***9-patch***](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftools%2Fhelp%2Fdraw9patch.html&ei=_edEVNCHGeTDmQXon4KICA&usg=AFQjCNFZFruIrVe2z2TCCVym4EQiuM2x4w&sig2=BBN5LwbD2VznEKy-ptjv3w&bvm=bv.77880786,bs.1,d.c2E) image for auto-scaling
5. When you load from assets, the "source" density is unknown, so this
   autoscaling is not performed. Hence, there is difference.

Comment: Why should I always use drawable folder? Will it affect the performance of my application? Currently I have almost 1000 images. And uploading these into drawable folder will create a mess for me.

Comment: @ Abrahamyan Samvel ..... If you have large number of images like 1000 ...... Look at caching the images in SD-CARD .... This will reduce the size of your `apk` file !

Comment: But can I protect them from being deleted or edited by the user

Comment: @ Abrahamyan Samvel ..... I Don't have complete info on that ..... I think user can't manually access those data ! ... Using `MODE-PRIVATE` you can make so that only your `app` can access those `data` ..... Or Using `MODE-APPEND` other apps can access the `data` ! ..... What i can tell is if there is `huge number` of images better `download` them in your `splash screen` and use them because its much `feasible` !

Answer (score 0):

> **You just define the imageView width and height in the xml layout then you should try this code it works perfectly for me**

```
public Bitmap getImageBitmap(String imgName){
    AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = mgr.open(imgName + ".png");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap(imageName);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```